# Populating Tableview Cells in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have tried searching up some tutorials on how to populate table views, but all I have found are old and outdated videos. I tried doing it from a slightly more recent one, and it does not work. I have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [chemarray addObject:@"2"];
    [chemarray addObject:@"test"];
    [chemarray addObject:@"3"];
    [chemarray addObject:@"science"];  
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [chemarray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"     forIndexPath:indexPath];

     cell.textLabel.text = [chemarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

according to this tutorial, when run, it should display the items in my array, but for me, it does not! Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you set your view controller as delegate of the table view? Does it create the cell or it doesn't?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You forgot to [register](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the nib/class for the cell identifier.

Form the Apple [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation:

> Important: You must register a class or nib file using the
>   [`registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW76) or
>   [`registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW93) method before calling the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`
>   method.

Here is an example for a plain `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

If you do not register the nib/class the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is essentially the same as `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. And it will not automatically create an instance for you.

Comment: where and how do I use this and put this

Comment: sorry, but I dont understand it... what does it mean by "cellClass:
The class of a cell that you want to use in the table"

Comment: Yes, see the example in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem.  If you are using iOS6, then I assume you are using a storyboard and that you associated the view controller with your custom class.

The solution then is to go into the storyboard, go to the properties for the cell in your tableview and change the Identifier value to "Cell".  There is no need to register the class in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

1. set the delegate to `uitableview.delegate = self`;
2. check if you have in declaration protocol  `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`
3. if you don't use the storyboard please be sure to init cell if cell==nil

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
   ```

Comment: So call dequeueReusableCell.... is useless because you dont "cache" the cell you create?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [chemarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Make sure you have `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in your `.h` and connected the `tableview` delegate, data source and `cellindentifier` Cell in `.xib`.